# Android- Re-size an image to match the screen's height

Tags: android, image, resize, background-image, android-relativelayout

In my app, for the background of a Relative Layout, I have an extremely large mesh wallpaper (bigger than any phone/table screen). So, I was wondering instead of having android resize it and make it look awful, I could resize it myself. What I want to do is resize the image (both vertically and horizontally, to keep it looking decent) until the image's and screen's height match.

Thanks, all help is appreciated- Lijap

Comment: use imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is something Google has put a very large amount of effort into.

Essentially, you should create different sizes for each of your target sizes/layouts.

This has extensive explanations (much better than I could give) in the [Google Dev Guide documents for Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

From that page:

> **Screen size**
>
> Actual physical size, measured as the screen's diagonal.
>   For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen sizes into four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and extra large.
>
> **Screen density**
>
> The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch).
>
> For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
>   For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen densities into four generalized densities: low, medium, high, and extra high.
>
> **Orientation**
>
> The orientation of the screen from the user's point of view. This is either landscape or portrait, meaning that the screen's aspect ratio is either wide or tall, respectively. Be aware that not only do different devices operate in different orientations by default, but the orientation can change at runtime when the user rotates the device.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> The total number of physical pixels on a screen. When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work directly with resolution; applications should be concerned only with screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and density groups.
>
> **Density-independent pixel (dp)**
>
> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>   The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

This way, your users will be looking at a bitmap that matches their device size.

Please let me know if you need help understanding the document, or if this doesn't properly answer your question.

Comment: So.. Looking through that I saw this: xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp so does that mean for ldpi etc. I should make the image those resolutions

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  So you want to create individual bitmaps for each of those sizes that you wish to target.  This will allow you to test it for each device in an emulator or on a device with that layout.\

Comment: Ok, thank you! But, since it says "at least" should I make the images a tad larger?

Comment: From what I understand, xlarge screens are very uncommon right now.  They will be more common in coming years, though, with 720p and better phones/tablets becoming more common.  For this case, I would recommend making the bitmaps sized to the "at least" specs here.  That is, your xlarge bitmaps are 960x720p, your normal are 640x480, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pheonixblade9's answer is correct but if you're determined to do some re-sizing yourself then you could possibly implement the [onSizeChanged() method of the ImageView class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Note however `onSizeChanged()` method is from the Super-Class, View.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is too large (especially if it's larger than any resolution out there) , you might get OOM (out of memory) error.

in such cases you must be memory efficient, and google has published some tutorials regarding this issue.

see: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html